# JAXB - Unexpected elements in XML output

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, eclipselink, jax-rs

I have a class called `Building`.

It has a list of `BuildingBenchAssociation` records (`List<BuildingBenchAssociation> benches`)

`BuildingBenchAssociation` has a composite id made up of `buildingId` and `benchId`
The ID is represented by separate class called `BuildingBenchAssociationPK`which has only two properties - `buildingId` and `benchId`

This is the output I get when I marshal a `Building` instance

```
<building buildingId="9">
<benches>
DOMRecord(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><buildingBenchAssociation><benchId>245865</benchId><buildingId>9</buildingId></buildingBenchAssociation>)
</benches>
<benches>
DOMRecord(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><buildingBenchAssociation><benchId>245866</benchId><buildingId>9</buildingId></buildingBenchAssociation>)
</benches>
<benches>
```

But I don't want `DOMRecord(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to appear in the output. Required output is something like this:

```
<building buildingId="9">
<benches>
<buildingBenchAssociation><benchId>245865</benchId><buildingId>9</buildingId></buildingBenchAssociation>
</benches>
<benches>
<buildingBenchAssociation><benchId>245866</benchId><buildingId>9</buildingId></buildingBenchAssociation>
</benches>
<benches>
```

**What's wrong and how do I correct it?** I am using the Eclipselink MOXy library.

Classes for reference:

Class 1

```
@Entity
@Table(name="building")
@XmlRootElement
public class Building implements Serializable {
....

private List<BuildingBenchAssociation> benchs = new ArrayList<BuildingBenchAssociation>();

    @XmlIDREF
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="building")
    public List<BuildingBenchAssociation> getBenchs() {
        return benchs;
    }

    public void setBenchs(List<BuildingBenchAssociation> benchs) {
        this.benchs = benchs;
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
@Entity
@Table(name="building_bench_rel")
@XmlRootElement
public class BuildingBenchAssociation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BuildingBenchAssociationPK idx;

    private Bench bench;
    private Building building;
    private byte alertFlags;
    private byte status;

    public BuildingBenchAssociation() {
            idx=new BuildingBenchAssociationPK();
    }

    @XmlID
    @XmlPath(".")
    @Id
    public BuildingBenchAssociationPK getIdx() {
        return this.idx;
    }

    public void setIdx(BuildingBenchAssociationPK id) {
        this.idx = id;
    }

    @Column(name="ALERT_FLAGS")
    public byte getAlertFlags() {
        return this.alertFlags;
    }

    public void setAlertFlags(byte alertFlags) {
        this.alertFlags = alertFlags;
    }

    @Column(name="STATUS", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public byte getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public void setStatus(byte status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @XmlIDREF
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BENCH_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Bench getBench() {
        return bench;
    }


    public void setBench(Bench bench) {
        this.bench = bench;
        this.idx.setBenchId(bench==null?null:bench.getBenchId());
    }

    @XmlIDREF
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BUILDING_ID",insertable=false,updatable=false)
    public Building getBuilding() {
        return building;
    }

    public void setBuilding(Building building) {
        this.building = building;
        this.idx.setBuildingId(building==null?null:building.getBuildingId());
    }

}
```

Class 3

```
@Embeddable
@XmlRootElement
public class BuildingBenchAssociationPK implements Serializable {
...

    private Integer buildingId;
    private Integer benchId;

    public BuildingBenchAssociationPK() {
    }

    @XmlKey
    @Column(name="BUILDING_ID")
    public Integer getBuildingId() {
        return this.buildingId;
    }
    public void setBuildingId(Integer buildingId) {
        this.buildingId = buildingId;
    }

    @XmlKey
    @Column(name="BENCH_ID")
    public Integer getBenchId() {
        return this.benchId;
    }
    public void setBenchId(Integer benchId) {
        this.benchId = benchId;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have cut out too much code to be able to answer.  We need to be able to see more of BuildingBenchAssociation.

Comment: I added the entire class now. Please see.

Comment: Which version of EclipseLink are you using?

Comment: org.eclipse.persistence.Version.getVersion() = 2.4.1

Comment: Interesting observation: I am using this with JAX-RS (Jersey) and when I change output type from XML to JSON, this part still shows up exactly the same way with all the XML syntax: DOMRecord(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><buildingBenchAssociation><benchId>245865</benchId><buildingId>9</buildingId></buildingBenchAssociation>)

Comment: The remaining parts are proper JSON but the above XML fragment appears as a blob of text in the JSON

Comment: @Priyank - In your use case the mappings are incorrect, currently they should be as I have given in my answer (see:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16426275/383861).  I have also opened the following enhancement request to make this use case easier to map (see:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/407460).  I have also opened a bug so that MOXy will throw an error message when the mappings are incorrect (see:  http://bugs.eclipse.org/407532).  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Below is how you can currently map this use case using MOXy.  I have opened the following enhancement request to make this use case easier to map:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/407460

---

**REFERENCED OBJECT**

**Embedded ID (EmployeeId)**

Below is an example of an embedded ID class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@Embeddable
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class EmployeeId {

    @Column(name="E_ID")
    BigDecimal eId;

    String country;

}
```

**Class with Embedded ID (Employee)**

We want to use the embedded ID class for as the key in an XML relationship.  Currently MOXy does not allow this to be done via annotations, so we will leverage the `@XmlCustomizer` annotation to programmatically modify the metadata.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeeId.class)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlCustomizer(EmployeeCustomizer.class)
public class Employee {

    @EmbeddedId
    @XmlPath(".")
    EmployeeId id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contact")
    List<PhoneNumber> contactNumber;

}
```

**Customize Mapping Metadata for Employee (EmployeeCustomizer)**

In the customizer class we will specify the XPaths for the mappings that compose the key on the embedded class.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;

public class EmployeeCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("eId/text()");
        descriptor.addPrimaryKeyFieldName("country/text()");
    }

}
```

---

**REFERRING OBJECT**

**PhoneNumber**

We are also going to need to programatically add the mapping based on the composite key, so once again we will use the `@XmlCustomizer` annotation.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@Entity
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlCustomizer(PhoneNumberCustomizer.class)
public class PhoneNumber {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="E_ID", referencedColumnName = "E_ID"),
        @JoinColumn(name="E_COUNTRY", referencedColumnName = "COUNTRY")
    })
    Employee contact;

}
```

**Customize Mapping Metadata for PhoneNumber (PhoneNumberCustomizer)**

In this customizer we will remove the default mapping, and programatically create the new one based on the composite keys.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.config.DescriptorCustomizer;
import org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLObjectReferenceMapping;

public class PhoneNumberCustomizer  implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
        descriptor.removeMappingForAttributeName("contact");

        XMLObjectReferenceMapping contactMapping = new XMLObjectReferenceMapping();
        contactMapping.setAttributeName("contact");
        contactMapping.setReferenceClass(Employee.class);
        contactMapping.addSourceToTargetKeyFieldAssociation("contact/@eID", "eId/text()");
        contactMapping.addSourceToTargetKeyFieldAssociation("contact/@country", "country/text()");
        descriptor.addMapping(contactMapping);
    }

}
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

The following demo code can be used to demonstrate that everything works:

**Demo**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Employee employee = (Employee) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(employee, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee>
   <eId>10</eId>
   <country>Canada</country>
   <contactNumber>
      <contact eID="10" country="Canada"/>
   </contactNumber>
   <contactNumber>
      <contact eID="10" country="Canada"/>
   </contactNumber>
</employee>
```

---

**FOR MORE INFORMATION**

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA/EmbeddedIdClass

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that link already. Also tried your suggestions here. It did not work.

Comment: If you see my comment on the question. The same XML fragment appears in JSON output. I think this could be a bug in MOXy or (less likely) Jersey.